# ASP.NET Export file to pdf

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am newbie. I have 8 files cshtml and I want to combine all to 1 file (index.cshtml, I will export it to pdf). Can you help me? What should I write code to index.cshtml.
Thank for your help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izEqA.png)

Comment: Hi @Nguyễn Chí Linh, do these cshtml file contain any tag helper or model data?

Comment: @Rena Hi. Yes, it has model data (@Model.ObjectDto.Attribute).

Comment: The model only contains in one cshtml file, right?

Comment: @Rena, it contains only model

Answer (score 0):

Hello Nguyễn Chí Linh,

If you know how to populate one viewmodel, you can combine these viewmodels into one like so:

```
public class viewModelGroup
{
   public ViewModel1 viewModel1 { get; set; } = new ViewModel1();
   public ViewModel2 viewModel2 { get; set; } = new ViewModel2();
}
```

For the output to PDF you can then use the nuget package manager to find many packages that will allow you to export the data to pdf. These packages come with their own documentation to show you how to convert your viewModelGroup into a PDF document.

Goodluck.